# Include listagg in an existing query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns DETAIL_FROM and DETAIL_TO

From and To can be Null or containing values from 'A' to 'D'

- If FROM:NULL and TO:NULL then all the values are returned : A,B,C,D
- if FROM:NULL and TO:value_1 then all the values until value_1 (including value_1) are returned
- if FROM:value2 and TO:NULL then all the values after value2 (including value_2) are returned
- if FROM:value3 and TO:value4 then all the values between value_3 nad value_4 are returned

Moreover, I have a master-detail relationship between two tables
and I want to check if each row of master have detail containing C value

My query is

```
With TBL_A as (
select 'A' as Type_Id from dual union all
select 'B' as Type_Id from dual union all
select 'C' as Type_Id from dual union all
select 'D' as Type_Id from dual
), TBL_B as (
select 1 as Master from dual union all
select 2 as Master from dual union all
select 3 as Master from dual union all
select 4 as Master from dual union all
select 5 as Master from dual  union all
select 6 as Master from dual        
), TBL_C as (
select 1 as Master,  '08' NUM,  'A' DETAIL_FROM ,  'D' DETAIL_TO from dual union all
select 2 as Master,  '08' NUM,  NULL DETAIL_FROM , 'D' DETAIL_TO from dual union all
select 3 as Master,  '08' NUM,  'A' DETAIL_FROM ,  'B' DETAIL_TO from dual union all
select 5 as Master,  '08' NUM,  'B' DETAIL_FROM ,  NULL DETAIL_TO from dual union all
select 5 as Master,  '08' NUM,  'A' DETAIL_FROM ,  'B' DETAIL_TO from dual 
)
select B.Master,  CASE WHEN C.NUM IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END c_exists
from TBL_B B, TBL_C C
WHERE B.Master = C.Master (+)
AND C.NUM (+) = '08'
AND 'C' IN (SELECT Type_Id  
                   FROM TBL_A 
                 WHERE Type_Id >= NVL(C.DETAIL_FROM,Type_Id)
                    AND Type_Id <= NVL(C.DETAIL_TO,Type_Id))
ORDER BY B.Master;
```

output :

```
|MASTER | C_EXISTS |
| 1     | Y        |
| 2     | Y        |
| 4     | N        |
| 5     | Y        |
| 6     | N        |
```

Could you help me please to retun also the values datail_from until detail_to with listag ?
Example output :

```
|MASTER | TYPE_LIST | C_EXISTS |
| 1     | A,B,C,D   | Y        |
| 2     | A,B,C,D   | Y        |
| 4     | NULL      | N        |
| 5     | B,C,D     | Y        |
| 6     | A,B       | N        |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
with
  tbl_a as (
    select 'A' as type_id from dual union all
    select 'B' as type_id from dual union all
    select 'C' as type_id from dual union all
    select 'D' as type_id from dual),
 tbl_b as (
    select 1 as master from dual union all
    select 2 as master from dual union all
    select 3 as master from dual union all
    select 4 as master from dual union all
    select 5 as master from dual  union all
    select 6 as master from dual),
  tbl_c as (
    select 1 as master, '08' num, 'A' detail_from , 'D' detail_to from dual union all
    select 2 as master, '08' num, null detail_from , 'D' detail_to from dual union all
    select 3 as master, '08' num, 'A' detail_from , 'B' detail_to from dual union all
    select 5 as master, '08' num, 'B' detail_from , null detail_to from dual union all
    select 6 as master, '08' num, 'A' detail_from , 'B' detail_to from dual)
select tb.Master, max(case ta.type_id when 'C' then 'Y' else 'N' end) c_exists,
       listagg(ta.type_id,',') within group (order by tb.master) type_list
from tbl_b tb
left outer join tbl_c tc on tc.master = tb.master and tc.num = '08'
left outer join tbl_a ta on tb.master = tc.master and ta.type_id >= nvl(tc.detail_from, ta.type_id) and ta.type_id <= nvl(tc.detail_to, ta.type_id)
group by tb.master
order by tb.master;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but
The output is not correct as Y should be the col C_EXISTS when C value exists in Type List.
Moreover, I think that the second left outer join should be inned join

Comment: Updated calculation of `c_exists` to give the expected output